# Angular2 tree not expanding by default if the entire tree is changed

Tags: angular, tree

I am working on [angular2 tree component](https://angular2-tree.readme.io/) where initially I am displaying the tree as

```
var nodes =
[
    {
        name: 'a',
        isExpanded: true,
        children: [
            {
                name: 'b',
                isExpanded: true,
                children: [
                    { name: 'c', }
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'b',
        isExpanded: true,
        children: [
            {
                name: 'a',
                children: [
                    { name: 'c' },
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

this works absolutely fine and the tree is displayed in expanded on a button click i am changing the entire tree and the new tree looks something like this

```
 changeTree{
  nodes =
        [
            {
                name: 'new Node a',
                isExpanded: true,
                children: [
                    {
                        name: ' new Node b',
                        isExpanded: true,
                        children: [
                            { name: 'new Node c', }
                        ]
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                name: 'new Node b',
                isExpanded: true,
                children: [
                    {
                        name: 'new Node a',
                        children: [
                            { name: ' new Node c' },
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ];

this.tree.treeModel.update(); 
this.tree.treeModel.expandAll();
}
```

I tried using this.tree.treeModel.update(); this.tree.treeModel.expandAll();
but still the tree is not getting expanded when a new tree is loaded.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do is add the `updateData` event to your tree-root ([docs](https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs/events#updatedata))

```
<tree-root #tree [nodes]="nodes" (updateData)="onUpdateData($event)"></tree-root>
```

This event fires everytime the tree model is updated. Within this event you can call the expandAll method to expand the tree

```
// component.ts
onUpdateData(tree){
    tree.treeModel.expandAll();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a word of warning - if you have a deep tree, calling expandAll inside onUpdateData($event) will slow your browser down.

Instead, i expand the node selectively.

Answer (score 0):

As of version 8.1.0, you could also implement your **onUpdateData** event like this:

```
// component.ts
onUpdateData(tree){
  tree.treeModel.calculateExpandedNodes();
}
```

See [this issue](https://github.com/CirclonGroup/angular-tree-component/issues/520) on GitHub for more details.